# How to close Modal de Materialize CSS with Vue

Tags: vue.js, materialize

I am trying to close a Modal of Materialize CSS if the validation is correct but I can not find the form.

The simplest thing was to do a type validation:
v-if = "showModal" and it works but leaves the background of the Modal and although click does not disappear. The background is a class named 'modal-overlay'

This is my code:

```
     <i class="material-icons modal-trigger tooltipped" style="margin-left: 2px; 
     color:#ffc107; cursor:pointer;" @click="getById(article), fillSelectCategories(), 
     titleModal='Edit', type='edit'" data-target="modal1">edit</i>
```

I imported M from the JS file of MaterilizeCSS

```
import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min";
```

**Method:**

```
    update(){
       var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.modal'); 
       var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(elem);
       console.log(instance)
```

That returns 'undefined'

I tried this too on the update() method:

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
elem.close();
M.Modal.close()
```

I initialize the modal from mounted and it works fine but I can not close it at the moment I require it.

```
mounted(){
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
}
```

But I know what else to try :(

Answer (score 2):

It really is difficult to know why things aren't working for you without looking further into your code, but I've created this simple example to demonstrate how it could be done ..

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    modalInstance: null,
    closeAfterTimeElapsed: true,
    seconds: 1
  },
  mounted() {
    const modal = document.querySelector('.modal')
    this.modalInstance = M.Modal.init(modal)

    const select = document.querySelector('select');
    M.FormSelect.init(select);

    M.updateTextFields();
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      if (this.closeAfterTimeElapsed) {
        setTimeout(() => { this.modalInstance.close() }, this.seconds * 1000)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">

  <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <button @click="handleClick" data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
  
  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <select v-model="closeAfterTimeElapsed">
        <option :value="false">False</option>
        <option :value="true">True</option>
      </select>
      <label>Close Modal After</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input id="seconds" type="number" v-model="seconds">
      <label for="seconds">Seconds</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pxwyznu/4/)